# Is there a standard naming convention in C++ for variable and function names?

Tags: c++, naming-conventions

I am new to C++ but not to programming. Normally, a language has one set of naming conventions that it abides by but with C++ there seems to be no standard on how to write variable and function names. I have seen some people use camel case (i.e. `myVariable, myFunction()`), some use all lower case (i.e. `myvariable, myfunction()`), and some use the underscore naming convention (i.e. `my_variable, my_function()`). Is there one naming convention that most of the C++ community uses or is there a *"use whatever convention you want just be consistent with it"* mentality?

Comment: You said "normally", but that's because so far you only knew programming languages each with one coherent community around it. C++ is not like it, and there are many languages like that too. Each subcommunity of C++ has its own loose naming conventions.

Comment: Some people prefer http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hungarian_notation

Comment: Yes C++ is a new type of beast for me. Coming from the Ruby, Objective C, and Java communities, C++ is a little different to say the least.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Normally, a language has one set of naming conventions that it abides by

While the standard library for most languages has a consistent convention, I know of very few *languages* that enforce a convention on the programmer.

And no, there is no common C++ naming convention.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on what libraries you are working within.

The standard library and STL use `names_like_this` for functions, classes, etc. Many third party libraries (Qt, etc) use `CamelCaseNames`.

There is no real standard as in Java.